# When I hit player API to Rounaz Cricket API it sends back to me "AccessDenied"

Tags: ios, swift, rest, api

When I try to access Rounaz Cricket API, server send me back

```
{
    "data": null,
    "status": false,
    "status_code": 403,
    "status_msg": "AccessDenied",
    "version": "2.0.2"
}
```

I get access key from my app and hit auth api and get access token

my API is:

https://rest.cricketapi.com/rest/v3/players_list/?access_token=xxxx&board=india&competition=international-t20&year=2018

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens. You can also edit out the info and flag your post for a moderator to redact the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response would indicate an issue with your access token. Perhaps it has expired, or there is another issue with your account.

Presumably this is the documentation you used to generate the access token?
https://www.cricketapi.com/docs/Core-API/Auth-API/

I would try to generate a new access token, although if that continues to fail, the cricketapi.com support might be a better place to obtain a solution. Especially if its account related.